How to input values from keyboard for a basic calculator in c#
I made a basic calculator on visual studio 2022 c#. The calculator works perfectly but I want to know how can I input values into the text box on the calcator using the keyboard instead of clicking on the buttons with the mouse?
I tried to start the calcator and enter values using the keyboard but nothing happened, it only inputs if I click on the button using the mouse result with trying to input using keyboard
Thanks in advance

Consider moving the focus back to the textbox in each button's Click event handler.

Set the KeyPreview Property of the FORM to True, then handle the KeyPress, KeyDown, and/or KeyUp events of the Form appropriately.

Use the Control.KeyPress(or KeyDown, depends on your choice) event for that. Here is the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.keypress?view=windowsdesktop-8.0
Using the System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e you can check which key was pressed
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.E)
    {
        // do something
    }
}

